# Android gradle 3.0.0 buildConfigField warning after updating

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I recently installed the latest Canary build of Android Studio which is currently using the Android Gradle plugin `3.0.0-alpha4` (previous was `2.3.3`).

I now get a warning for all of my buildConfigFields:

```
buildTypes {
        def BOOLEAN = "boolean"
        def STRING = "String"
        def INT = "int"
        def TRUE = "true"
        def FALSE = "false"
        def SOME_PER_BUILD_TYPE_FIELD = "SOME_PER_BUILD_TYPE_FIELD"

 debug {
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, SOME_PER_BUILD_TYPE_FIELD, FALSE
}

 release {
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, SOME_PER_BUILD_TYPE_FIELD, TRUE
}
```

The warnings read like:

```
Warning:BuildType(debug): buildConfigField 'SOME_PER_BUILD_TYPE_FIELD' value is being replaced: false -> false
Warning:BuildType(debug): buildConfigField 'SOME_STRING_FIELD' value is being replaced: "999" -> "999"
```

And there is like 100 of them for my various fields and build types. How do I fix them and what is the warning actually telling me?

Comment: Not sure about how to fix this, but the warning is self explanatory: build system just warns you that some `buildConfigField` is being re-assigned. The two shown fields are being re-assigned to the same value, which hints that either A) your build script is misconfigured and evaluates some expression twice B) your build script have duplicate assignments C) gradle by itself evaluates the build script twice, and warns you about its own actions

Comment: I had some strange warnings/errors with 3.0.0-alpha4 as well, which were fixed by moving back to 3.0.0-alpha3 strangely enough. Maybe give that a try?

Comment: Yeah I'm fairly sure this is pointing to an issue in my build script as @Vasiliy mentioned. I define default debug and release build types with config fields but also build types for each other flavor, and it looks like because I am defining them in both `debug` and `debug_flavor_1` etc., gradle is pointing that out as an error where it didn't before. I have renamed the default debug and release types to `debug_default` and `release_default` and all of the errors seem to have gone.

Comment: @Vasiliy if you answer with that I shall mark it as such :)

Comment: Lastly I needed to use `initWith debug` on the custom debug variants so they inherit BuildConfig.DEBUG as true

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Build system warns you that some `buildConfigField` is being re-assigned.

The two shown fields are being re-assigned to the same value, which hints that one of the following scenarios might be happening:

1. your build script is misconfigured and evaluates some expression twice
2. your build script have duplicate assignments
3. gradle by itself evaluates the build script twice, and warns you about its own actions

Comment: Any idea on how to suppress the warning. replacing buildConfigValues dependent on build-variants is a normal use case

Comment: @for3st, I don't know.

Comment: @for3st did you figure out how to suprress this warning?

Comment: I looked into suppressing the warning recently. From the source it appears this information is being logged at logging level INFO, so it should not be present in console output by default (default log level is LIFECYCLE which is less verbose than INFO). However, the docs include this note: "The rich components of the console (build status and work in progress area) are displayed regardless of the log level used. Before Gradle 4.0 those rich components were only displayed at log level LIFECYCLE or below." So I'm not sure there's a way to suppress the message in the rich components :/

Comment: Sources: [Logging docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html), [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/decc420635367651f4ddaa937032e1ed1762bd50/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/dsl/BuildType.java#151)

Comment: Monitor this issue for potential fix (:fingerscrossed:) https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68849483

Comment: It's since been fixed! 

Answer (score 25):

The reason is correctly mentioned by [Vasiliy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44632658). Just to add a little to it, one possible reason for it could be when you have a buildType that is initialised with any other buildType. e.g. consider the following build configurations:

```
debug {
    buildConfigField 'boolean', 'ENABLE_CRASH_REPORTING', 'false'
}
stage {
    initWith(buildTypes.debug)
    buildConfigField 'boolean', 'ENABLE_CRASH_REPORTING', 'true'
}
release {
    buildConfigField 'boolean', 'ENABLE_CRASH_REPORTING', 'true'
}
```

In this case, you will get warning for buildType stage

> Warning:BuildType(stage): buildConfigField 'ENABLE_CRASH_REPORTING' value is being replaced: false -> true

The reason is pretty simple and obvious that **stage** inherits all fields from **debug** and then **stage** replaces it because you might want to assign them different value for **stage** *(like in the case above)*. A possible workaround could be replacing

```
initWith(buildTypes.debug)
```

with

```
signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
```

This will eliminate the signing error you normally get when building stage builds. But the main difference here in the configuration now is; **stage** will not inherit build variables from **debug** in this case and therefore you will not get any warning for this too. Also you will have to redefine all build variables in **stage** in this case as (already mentioned) **stage** is no more inherited from **debug**

Comment: If you are able to move build variables to defaultConfig rather than in debug it won't produce a warning

Comment: This is not really a good solution - then you have more then two build types living without initWith becomes cumbersome pain and error-prone

Comment: Quite a regular reason, but a very specific solution which usually doesn't solve the problem satisfyingly: I'm using initWith to prevent duplication of several buildType configurations, including minifyEnabled, shrinkResources and proguardFiles. Because of this I think initWith is a really useful configuration for a buildType. There is a single buildConfigField I'd like to overwrite, but any other configs I'd like to 'initWith' (which don't have to do anything with signingConfig), so this solution doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

The most naive solution is to move all `buildConfigField` in `debug` section to `defaultConfig` section.